# How to check mobile data usage programmatically?

Tags: android, usage-statistics, android-data-usage

The question is pretty straight forward, How do I find out how much mobile data (in GB or MB) has the user used in the current month?

As it has been reported as off topic, I want to clarify that the data usage is supposed to be checked via code in an app.

Is there some code I can use to check for the users used data?

Comment: @ModularSynth no, it's not. sorry didn't explained well. I need to do it via code in an app of course

Comment: Guys this question isn't off topic at all. He explained it so why all this downvotes?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is actually very [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), here.

Comment: Try                                                                               Toast.makeText(this,  android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()+"Bytes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                     
getMobileRxBytes() Return number of bytes received across mobile networks since device boot.

Answer (score 12):

See:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(this, android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()+"Bytes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

getMobileRxBytes() Return number of bytes received across mobile networks since device boot.

Comment: In my Galaxy note 10 (2022), I get 0 from this.